# Laravel - How can I set the orderBy on a FK using Eloquent?

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I have Product model and I have Categories model. I also have a pivot table called `category_product`. I am trying to set an `orderBy` on my CategoryController.

**Product.php**

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id');
}
```

**Category.php**

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

**CategoryController.php**

```
public function index()
{
    // works
    $categories = Category::where('parent_category_id', 0)->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();

    // Unknown column 'category_product.sort_key'
    $categories = ProductCategory::where('parent_category_id', 0)->orderBy('category_product.sort_key', 'asc')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();


    return view('category.index', compact('categories'));
}
```

My pivot table looks like this:

```
product_id
category_id
sort_order
```

I am following the suggested table naming conventions. I've even passed in the pivot table name to be safe. - I'm not sure how to include the pivot table in my query.

I also believe this is a reason I can't access columns correctly. 
For example:

**Product.php**

```
$this->categories->myColumn // Undefined property
```

My migration looks like this:

```
...
$table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

***EDIT***

I have updated the logic as suggested, and I still don't think I've got the join quite right yet.

**Category.php**

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id')
        ->withPivot('sort_key');
}
```

**Product.php**

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id')
        ->withPivot('sort_key');
}
```

**CategoryController.php**

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::where('parent_category_id', 0)
        ->orderBy('sort_order', 'asc')
        ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
        ->get();

    return view('category.index', compact('categories'));
}

Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sort_order' in 'order clause
```

If I take the `->orderBy('sort_order', 'asc')` all is well. I have also tried `->orderBy('category_product.sort_order', 'asc')` and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, according to [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), the inverse of a many-to-many relationship isn't hasMany, it's belongsToMany. Line 3 of your Category.php file should read:

```
return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
```

If you want to use the `sort_order` column in your pivot table when you retrieve either a Category or Product model, you need to include the withPivot() method in both your Product and Category model definitions like so:

**Product.php**

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id')
    ->withPivot('sort_order');
}
```

**Category.php**

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id')
    ->withPivot('sort_order');
}
```

Once that is done, say you want to get all of the products for the category whose id is 2. You could do something like this in your CategoryController:

**CategoryController.php**

```
public function index()
{
    // Get all products for category with an id of 2
    $Products = Category::find(2)->products;

    // Assign the sort_table attribute to each Product model. Can be done
    // in the model definition by setting an accessor attribute. Setting
    // it here for expediency.

    foreach($Products as $Product) $Product->sort_order = $Product->pivot->sort_order;

    // Sort products in descending order using the sort_order column from
    // the pivot table.
    $SortedProducts = $Products->sortByDesc('sort_order');
}
```

That final line which sorts the products is a [Collection Method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections). Collection Methods are almost always more powerful than hardcoding a sort order in your model since you can make a chain of many methods fluently, for example:

```
$SortedProducts = $Products->where('status', 'available')
                           ->sortBy('product_name');
```

You also make your code a heck of a lot cleaner and potentially avoid making yet another database query later in your application simply to sort your results in a different fashion, thereby making everything that little bit faster.

**Edit**

When you call the `Category::` facade, what you're telling Laravel to do is to make queries on the table that you have defined in your Category model. By default, it's the same as the model name. With that in mind, unless you have a `sort_order` on your `categories` table, Laravel will complain that it can't find the `sort_order` column.

If you do something like this, however:

```
public function index()
{
    $Products = Category::find(2)->products;

    $products = $Products->toArray();

    var_dump($products);
}
```

... you'll notice a `pivot` key along with a `sort_order` sub-key.

To put it simply, Laravel will attach the columns of the pivot table only if the pivot table is actually used, like in the example above. If you want to get the `sort_order` column without calling on the many-to-many relationship that you defined in your Product and Category model, a simple join will do the trick:

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::where('parent_category_id', 0)
        ->join('category_product', 'categories.id', '=', category_product.category_id)
        ->orderBy('category_product.sort_order', 'asc')
        ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
        ->get();

    return view('category.index', compact('categories'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer Alex! I'm still running into a bit of trouble - I've edited my question above.